# Javascript replace string with 8 and 9 doesn't work...but other numbers do...?

Tags: javascript, replace

Check out this script... run and see the oddity..

http://jsfiddle.net/BjJTc/

From jsfiddle

```
var m = 'Jan07';
var mm = 'Jan';
alert(m.replace(mm, ''));
alert(parseInt(m.replace(mm, '')));

var m = 'Jan08';
var mm = 'Jan';
alert(m.replace(mm, ''));
alert(parseInt(m.replace(mm, '')));


var m = 'Jan09';
var mm = 'Jan';
alert(m.replace(mm, ''));
alert(parseInt(m.replace(mm, '')));


var m = 'Jan10';
var mm = 'Jan';
alert(m.replace(mm, ''));
alert(parseInt(m.replace(mm, '')));
```

Comment: It is not a problem with `parseInt`, not the replacing.

Answer (score 10):

This is an Octal issue: try `parseInt(val, 10)`. The leading zero makes it believe it's octal. [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) takes a second optional parameter radix:

> **radix**  An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned
>   string. While this parameter is optional, always specify it to
>   eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. 
>   Different implementations produce different results when a radix is
>   not specified.

So:

```
parseInt('09') // 0
parseInt('09', 10); // 9
```

Comment: Thou shalt always supply a radix to `parseInt`.

Comment: jsLint at jsFiddle warns about that.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: Better still: use `Number` to convert a string to a numeric value

Comment: @Kooilc, not if you want an integer

Answer (score 4):

You are running into a problem with the radix.  Javascript is interpreting `07, 08, 09` as octal numbers.  Decimal 7 and Octal 07 evaluate to the same number, while 8 & 9 do not.

Include the base 10 radix as the second param to all of your `parseInt()` calls:

```
var m = 'Jan08';
var mm = 'Jan';
alert(m.replace(mm, ''));
alert(parseInt(m.replace(mm, ''), 10));
// ------------------------------^^^^^^
```

Comment: @jackJoe Decimal 7 is the same as Octal 07. But 8 & 9 are not.

Comment: Not strange!  7 in octal equals 7 in decimal!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the year from the string you have, you could attempt to parse it as a date then extract the number of years...

```
var m = 'Jan07';
var d = Date.parse('01' + m); // Parse the 1st of the month
var y=Math.floor(d/(1000*60*60*24*365.24)) + 1970; // Convert to years since 1970, then add 1970
alert(y);
```

Not to most elegant of solutions, but will get you the year from your MMMyy format.

Answer (score 0):

Or just lose the leading letters and any leading 0-

```
m='Jan08';
mm=/^\D+0?/,'');
alert(m.replace(mm, ''));
```